# A shortcut in Galois theory

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

*How could we prove Galois correspondence without using Dedekind’s Lemma on group characters, Artin’s lemma and the primitive element theorem ?*

I just came across Meinolf Geck's article *On the characterization of Galois extensions* on [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.3853v1.pdf), that you can find in [Amer. Math. Monthly 121 (2014), no. 7, p. 637–639](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.121.07.637?uid=3738016&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21105979816053) which answers the question, and my answer - that I make a community wiki, will be *inspired* from this article.

Some remarks : Dedekind's lemma states that if $G$ is a monoid and $k$ a field then any familly of elements of $\textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Mon.}}(G,k^{\times})$ is free over $k$. This implies that if $L/K$ is a finite extension then $\textrm{Aut}_K(L)$ is finite of order smaller than the degree $[L:K]$ of the extension (the degree inequality). This fact can be shown without Dedekind's lemma, this is what Geck does in the corollary 4 of the arxiv version of its paper. Artin's lemma states that if $L$ is a field a $G$ a finite group of field automorphisms of $L$ and $K = L^G$ then $L/K$ is a Galois extension of degree $|G|$. The Galois correspondance is the one from the corollary 1 in my answer, completed by the corollary 2 following it.

Comment: Note that, as mentioned below, it's acceptable (and even encouraged) to answer your own questions on stackexchange sites:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: A main issue with this question is that it does not explain what is being cut out. I don't think every text on Galois theory follows the same line of reasoning (though I did not check), so it is not clear what is your starting point (previous results that can be used), nor quite exactly what is the ending point ("Galois correspondence" is rather vague; certainly you are referring to some precise statement of it), and only vaguely what intermediate steps are to be avoided. I think you should provide at least some indation of these.

Comment: I will edit the question again to try to address this. I do nevertheless find quite bizarre to read you writing that "Galois correspondance" is vague.

Answer (score 10):

**Proposition 1.** Let $K\to L$ be a field extension of finite degree. Then $L$ is not the union of finitely many subfields $M$ such that $K\to M\subsetneq L$.

*Proof.* Assume that $K$ is finite and let $q=\mathop{\rm Card}( K)$. Then $L$ is finite as well, and let $n=[L:K]$ so that $\mathop{\rm Card}(L)=q^n$. If $M$ is a subextension of $L$, then $\mathop{\rm Card}( L)=q^m$, for some integer $m$ dividing $n$; moreover, $x^{q^m}=x$ for every $x\in L$. Then the union of all strict sub-extensions of $L$ has cardinality at most $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} q^m =\frac{q-q^n}{1-q} < q^n$. Suppose now that $K$ is infinite, then the proposition follows from the fact that a finite union of strict subspace of a $K$-vector space $E$ is not equal to $E$. Let indeed $(E_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ be a family of strict subspaces of $E$ and let us prove by induction on $n$ that $E\neq \bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i$. The cases $n\leq1$ are obvious. By induction we know that for every $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, the union $\bigcup_{i\neq j}E_i$ is distinct from $E$, hence select an element $x\in E$ such that $x\not\in E_2\cup \dots\cup E_n$. The desired result follows if, by chance, $x\not\in E_1$. Otherwise, choose $y\in E\setminus E_1$. For $s\neq t\in K$, and $i\in\{2,\dots,n\}$, observe that $y+sx$ and $y+tx$ cannot both belong to $E_i$, for this would imply that $(s-t)x\in E_i$, hence $x\in E_i$ since $s\neq t$. Consequently, there are at most $n-1$ elements $s\in K$ such that $y+sx\in \bigcup_{i=2}^nE_i$. Since $K$ is infinite, there exists $s\in K$ such that $y+sx\not\in\bigcup_{i=2}^n E_i$. Then $y+sx\not\in E_1$, neither, since $x\in E_1$ and $y\in E_1$. This proves that $E\neq \bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i$. $\square$

Let $K\to L$ be a field extension and let $P\in K[T]$. We say that $P$ is split in $L$ if it is a product of linear factors in $L[T]$. We say that $P$ is separable if all of its roots (in some extension where it is split) have multiplicity $1$. We say that $K\to L$ is a splitting extension  of $P$ if $P$ is split in $L$ and if $L$ is the subextension of $K$ generated by the roots of $P$ in $L$. Finally, we let $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$ be the set of $K$-linear automorphisms of $L$; it is a group under composition.

**Proposition 2.** Let $K\to L$ be a finite extension of fields  and let $G=\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$. Then $\mathop{\rm Card}( G)\leq [L:K]$. Moreover, the following  conditions are equivalent:

1. One has $\mathop{\rm Card}( G)=[L:K]$
2. There exists an irreducible separable  polynomial  $P\in K[T]$ such that $\deg(P)=[L:K]$ and which is split in $L$
3. The extension $K\to L$ is a splitting extension of a separable polynomial in $K[T]$
4. One has $K=L^G$

*Remark.* In the conditions of (2), let us fix a root $z\in L$ of $P$. One has $L=K(z)$. Moreover, the map $f\mapsto f(z)$ is a bijection from $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$ to the set of roots of $P$ in $L$.

*Proof.* (a) Let us prove that $\mathop{\rm Card} (G)\leq [L:K]$. Let $m\in\mathbf N$ be such that $m\leq \mathop{\rm Card}( G)$ and let $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_m$ be distinct elements of $G$. For $1\leq j\leq m$, let $M_{i,j}$ be the subfield of $L$ consisting of all $x\in L$ such that  $\sigma_i(x)=\sigma_j(x)$. It is a strict subextension of $L$ because $\sigma_i\neq\sigma_j$. Consequently, $L$ is not the union of the subfields $M_{i,j}$ and there exists an element $z\in L$ such that $\sigma_i(z)\neq \sigma_j(z)$  for all $i\neq j$. Let $P$ be the minimal polynomial of $z$. Then the set $\{\sigma_1(z),\dots,\sigma_m(z)\}$ consists of distinct roots of $P$, hence $\deg(P)\geq m$. In particular, $m\leq [L:K]$. Since this holds for every $m\leq \mathop{\rm Card}( G)$, this shows that $\mathop{\rm Card}( G)\leq [L:K]$.

(b) If one has $\mathop{\rm Card}( G)=[L:K]$, then taking $m=\mathop{\rm Card}( G)$, we get an irreducible polynomial $P\in K[T]$ of degree $m$, with $m$ distinct roots  in $L$. Necessarily, $P$ is separable and  split in $L$. This gives (1)$\Rightarrow$(2). The implication (2)$\Rightarrow$(3) is obvious. (1)$\Rightarrow$(4). Let $M=L^G$. One has $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)=\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)=G$. Consequently, $\mathop{\rm Card}(G)\leq [L:M]$. Since $\mathop{\rm Card}( G)=[L:K]=[L:M][M:K]$, this forces $M=K$. (4)$\Rightarrow$(3). There exists a $G$-invariant subset $A$ of $L$ such that $L=K(A)$. Then $P=\prod_{a\in A}(T-a)$ is split in $L$, and is $G$-invariant. Consequently, $P\in K[T]$. By construction, $P$ is separable and $L$ is a splitting extension of $P$. (3)$\Rightarrow$(1). Let $M$ be a subextension of $L$ and let $f\colon M\to L$ be a $K$-morphism. Let $a\in A$ and let $Q_a$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $M$. The association $g\mapsto g(a)$ defines a bijection between the set of extensions of $f$ to $M(a)$ and the set of roots of $Q_a$ in $L$. Since $P(a)=0$, the polynomial $Q_a$ divides $P$, hence it is separable and split in $L$. Consequently, $f$ has exactly $\deg(Q_a)=[M(a):M]$ extensions to $M(a)$. By a straightforward induction on $\mathop{\rm Card}(B)$, for every subset $B$ of $A$, the set of $K$-morphisms from $K(B)$ to $L$ has cardinality $[K(B):K]$. When $B=A$, every such morphism is surjective, hence $\mathop{\rm Card}(\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L))=[L:K]$. $\square$

**Definition.** If these equivalent conditions hold, we say that the finite extension $K\to L$ is *Galois*.

**Corollary 1.** Let $K\to L$ be a finite Galois extension. The maps $H\to L^H$ and $M\to \mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$ are bijections, inverse one of the other, between subgroups of $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$ and subextensions $K\to M\subset L$.

*Proof.* (a) For every subextension $K\to M\subset L$, the extension $M\subset L$ is Galois. In particular, $M=L^{\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)}$ and $\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)=[L:M]$.

(b) Let $H\subset\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$ and let $M=L^H$. Then $M\to L$ is a Galois extension and $[L:M]=\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$; moreover, one has $H\subset\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$ by construction. Let us prove that $H=\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$. Let $z\in L$ be any element whose minimal polynomial $P_z$ over $M$ is split and separable in $L$. One has $\mathop{\rm Card}(\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L))=\deg(P_z)$. On the other hand, the polynomial $Q_z=\prod_{\sigma\in H}(T-\sigma(z))\in L[T]$ divides $P_z$ and is $H$-invariant, hence it belongs to $L^H[T]=M[T]$. This implies that $P_z=Q_z$, hence $\mathop{\rm Card}(H)=\deg(P_z)=\mathop{\rm Card}(\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L))$. Consequently, $H=\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$. $\square$

**Corollary 2.** Let $K\to L$ be a Galois extension and let $K\to M\to L$ be an intermediate extension. The extension $M\to L$ is Galois too. Moreover, the following assertions are equivalent :

1. The extension $K\to M$ is Galois
2. $\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$
3. For every $\sigma\in\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$, one has $\sigma(M)\subset M$

*Proof.* (a) Let $P\in K[T]$ be a separable polynomial of which $K\to L$ is a splitting field. Then $M\to L$ is a splitting extension of $P$, hence $M\to L$ is Galois.

(b) (1)$\Rightarrow$(2): Let $\sigma\in \mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$. Let $z$ be any element of $M$ and let $P\in K[T]$ be its minimal polynomial. One has $P(\sigma(z))=\sigma(P(z))=0$, hence $\sigma(z)$ is a root of $P$; in particular, $\sigma(z)\in M$. Consequently, the restriction of $\sigma$ to $M$ is a $K$-morphism from $M$ to itself; it is necessarily a $K$-automorphism. We thus have defined a map from $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$ to $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(M)$; this map is a morphism of groups. Its kernel is $\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$, so that this group is normal in $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$.

(2)$\Rightarrow$(3): Let $\sigma\in\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$ and let $H=\sigma\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)\sigma^{-1}$. By construction, one has $\sigma(M)\subset L^G$. On the other hand, the hypothesis that $\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$ is normal in $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$ implies that $G=\mathop{\rm Aut}_M(L)$, so that $L^G=M$. We thus have proved that $\sigma(M)\subset M$.

(3)$\Rightarrow$(1): Let $A$ be a finite subset of $M$ such that $M=K(A)$ and let $B$ be its orbit under $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$. The polynomial $\prod_{b\in B}(T-b)$ is separable and invariant under $\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$, hence belongs to $K[T]$. By assumption, one has $B\subset M$. This implies that $K\to M$ is Galois. $\square$

**Proposition 3.** Let $L$ be a field, let $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $L$ and let $K=L^G$. Then $K\to L$ is Galois, and $G=\mathop{\rm Aut}_K(L)$.

*Proof.* If $G$ is trivial it is trivial, if not, for each non trivial $g\in G$ pick an $a_g\in L$ such that $g(a_g)\not=a_g$ and note $X = \cup_{g\in G\backslash\{1\}} O(a_g)$. The set $X$ is clearly $G$ stable so that $M:=K(X)$ is also $G$-stable. Now each $a_g$ is algebraic over $K$, as it is root of $P(T) = \prod_{\lambda\in O(a_g)} (X-\lambda) \in L[X]$ which has in fact coefficients in $K$. You can express $P$'s coefficients as symmetric polynomials in the elements of $O(a_g)$ and this shows that they are fixed by $G$, and are therefore in $K$. This implies in fact that each element of $X$ is algebraic over $K$, and as $X$ is finite, $M$ is algebraic over $K$. By stability we have a restriction map $\varphi : G\to \textrm{Aut}_K (M)$ which is injective by definition of the $a_g$'s. Then you have $M^{\textrm{Aut}_K (M)} \subseteq M^G$ and the latter being included in $L^G = K$ you see that $M^{\textrm{Aut}_K (M)} = K$. As we saw that $M/K$ is finite, it is Galois, and then the correspondance shows that $G = \textrm{Aut}_K (M)$. Now take $a\in L$. The same argument shows that $M(O(a))/K$ is Galois with group $G$, the same group than $M/K$'s. The correspondance shows that $M(O(a)) = M$, and this is for any $a\in L$. Therefore $L = M$ is finite. Then as $G \subset \textrm{Aut}_K (L)$ we have $K\subseteq L^{\textrm{Aut}_K (L)} \subseteq L^G = K$ showing that $L^{\textrm{Aut}_K (L)} = K$ : the extension $L/K$ is Galois and $G = \textrm{Aut}_K (L)$. $\square$

Comment: You have not asked any question at all here. It's more like a blog post. Also you include *more* than what is in Geck's paper (at least the arXiv version) and you should be clearer about that. In particular, your remark at the end has a gap: the equation $L^{{\rm Aut}(L/K)} = K$ does *not* imply $L/K$ is a Galois extension unless you prove $L/K$ is a finite extension. That is really the hardest part of this result (Artin's theorem), and the approach to that I know relies on the very primitive element theorem for finite separable (not necessarily Galois) extensions that you are avoiding.

Comment: I did ask a question (see its original version) even if it wasn't maybe explicit in the orginal version of the question. I hope that its clearer now after edit. I retrieved the remark for now.

Comment: I see. But you ask sort of a fake question in the OP because you are merely setting things up to immediately answer your own question. That is, you did not sincerely ask the question seeking an answer, as you already had an answer.  In your answer you are asking an actual question that you don't know the answer to, and *that* should really be asked in the OP.

Comment: @KCd SE encourages this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking Even though I agree there shouldn't be another question in the answer.

Comment: @hjhjhj57, okay. I have nothing philosophically against this post. My reason for raising a complaint is that I recall in the past some other people posted their own work as questions and answers and the community felt this way of essentially turning the site into a blog post was not fair use.

Comment: @KCd Keith, I can, if you want, disclose to you privately my identity, so that you will see that I am not Geck. ;-) My question and its answer do indeed promote Geck's paper, but answering its own question is totally kosher here, so that it could be a way to pin here once for all nice and original results such this one. About the side effect of promoting someone's paper, I was balanced between mentioning Geck and its paper or not, and thought that is was disrespectful and dishonest not doing it while knowing it. Nevertheless, I will remove any personal judgment about the paper in a next edit.

Comment: It really did not occur to me that you might be Geck and I wasn't trying to suggest that in anything I wrote before.

Comment: @KCd I know, but I prefer to be clear.

Comment: The way that answering your own question has usually been interpreted on this website is, you post a question to which you don't know the answer, then you figure it out (perhaps after some helpful hints from others), then you post your answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So that the way I am using it is somehow tolerated, but but kosher *per se* ?... Even with the community wiki option that I used ?

Comment: It's established ppolicy that this website is not for publishing one's own results --- that's what blogs are for.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I totally disagree with you. Self-answering immediately is included in what this website describes itself to be for. Click on "Ask a Question" and see that it links straight to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/!

Comment: @user21820, what this website describes itself to be for, and what its community of users have come to a consensus that it actually is for, may be two very different things.

Comment: @KCd The remark at the end was actually true. It is now a proposition.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your last remark made me think about the movie *In the loop*, namely the scene where Karen Clarke is arguing about wheter a certain committee should be or not officially or not called war commitee of future planning committee, and where Linton Barwick, pointing to a glass of water, says : "Well, Karen, unofficially, we can call anything whatever we want. I mean, unofficially, this is a shoe, but it's not, Karen, it is a glass of water. And this is the Future Planning Committee."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Actually I fully agree that we shouldn't use this website like we do a blog, but my point is that something needs to be changed on the "Ask a Question" page to make it consistent with the consensus viewpoint. Who here wants inconsistency? =)

Comment: Well, we know that any system strong enough to be complete must be inconsistent. In any event, sounds like you could post a feature request to the meta site, asking for a change to "Ask a Question".

Comment: By the way, this approach does not seem to be new. For example, Theorem 10.1 of [these](https://www.math.ens.fr/enseignement/telecharger_fichier.php?fichier=1452) lecture notes seem using similar techniques.

Comment: Geck's paper was published in August–September 2014 issue of  Amer. Math. Monthly (issue numer 121.)

Comment: The proof of proposition 1 in the case of finite fields is so confusing and riddled with typos, I'd have been better off with it not being proven at all.  Anyway, of course finite extensions are finitely generated because their nonzero elements form a _cyclic_ group as is easily proven using FTo Abelian Groups.   At any rate, this is a nice simplification of my algebra text and I found it useful.  Dummit and Foote's use of characters felt quite unmotivated.

Comment: @JakeMirra, please feel free to correct the typos, after all, we're all here to enlight each other even on the form. Regarding your confusion, I can only say that it's a per se personal sentiment. After, there are also people confused by the semidirect product or by Galois categories. Do you want me to make the proof of prop maybe more clear for you ?

Comment: @Olórin I don't dare, I'm not an expert in the subject, so am too likely to make it worse without realizing it.  But I insist it's not user friendly if a diligent reader like myself can't understand it, at least if your target audience is meant to include relative novices in Galois Theory, which I think it should.

Comment: @JakeMirra You *should* correct the typos *especially* as you're *not* an expert in the subject. As assistant conductors take little notes for conductors, preparing themselves with this petty work for being one day conductors themselves. But I insist there are people confused by Galois theory or semidirect product (not because Galois theory or semidirect product are confusing but often because they generally tend to be confused). If you can't understand it, I would strongly advise to you to look diligently for the reason(s) of this within yourself *first*. You're no audience.